# How do i list all opened application in a file using windows service C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

i found a piece of code which is written in console application and also working.
here is the code..

```
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in processlist)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID :{1} Window Title :{2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
                }
            }
```

and i have modified the code like this...

```
            StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("D:\\loop.txt", true);
            str.WriteLine("**** List of Application *********");

            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in processlist)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    str.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID :{1} Window Title :{2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
                }
            }
            str.close();
```

but it is not working in windows service. Did i made a mistake? i am new to windows service . is there any one can help me? what should i do?

Comment: What's the error you are getting ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504441/not-all-info-about-process-in-process-getprocesses-when-run-in-service-by-local

Comment: I am not getting any error. but in loop file only first line of the program is written that is " ****** List of Application******  ".

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to [Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the stream

Quoted:

> You must call Close to ensure that all data is correctly written out to the underlying stream. Following a call to Close, any operations on the StreamWriter might raise exceptions. If there is insufficient space on the disk, calling Close will raise an exception.

Corrected code :

```
StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("D:\\loop.txt", true);
str.WriteLine("**** List of Application *********");

Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process process in processlist)
{
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
   {
       str.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID :{1} Window Title :{2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
   }
}

str.Close(); // You need to close the stream
```

Alternative : [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

```
using (StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("D:\\loop.txt", true))
{
     str.WriteLine("**** List of Application *********");

     Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

     foreach (Process process in processlist)
     {
          if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
          {
            str.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID :{1} Window Title :{2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: Actually i have closed stream , here i just didn't mention that . Thanks for the "using " concept.